# Is a man a consort of a queen, or to a queen?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Consort *of,* or *to*?

Would we say "the Consort **of** Queen Elizabeth" or "the Consort **to** Queen Elizabeth"?

Comment: Either one. _Consort_ is both a kinship term (hence allowing the possessive and _of_) and a state position, which licenses the _to_.

Comment: I agree with John Lawler that either works. "**Of**" shows an association with its object noun and tends to be understood as stative. "**To**" likewise shows an association with its object noun but tends to indicate that the association *goes towards* the object noun. Compare "The key **of** the door" and "the key **to** the door", where the "of" indicates the condition of the key, and the latter implies the key that fits into the door. The "to form is sometimes known as "the beneficial dative."